# How to create a custom query inside a plugin in Craft?

Tags: plugin-development

Can you give an example of returning entries from a section in JSON format using a custom query?

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough:

```
$query = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$query->section = 'mySection';
$results = $query->find();
```

You can obviously refine the query before calling `find()`:

```
$query->limit   = null;
$query->myCustomField = 'value';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to "json encode" the result so that i can use it in my javascript , its hard for me to convert the result using elements criteria is there a way that i can only get the results in json format

Comment: Well, you can return json_encode($results). Maybe this can help: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI